# Python - Dataframe column conversion

Tags: regex, type-conversion

I'm new on python and I'm trying to convert a column of a dataframe with strings (like 10,000+ or 1,000+) with regex in order to eliminate characters (`+` and `,`) and then convert them into integer.
How can I do that?

I've tried with regex functions but it doesn't work

```
convert_installs = re.compile('(?P<amount>\d*).(?P<unit>\d*)')
```

is it correct for finding what I want to save?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubvwa.png)

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us a few lines of your dataframe? It will help anyone to understand what you were trying to do.

Comment: Hi, I insert the screenshot in the question. I have the "Installs" column done by strings and I have to converte those strings into numbers eliminating the "," and "+"

Answer (score 0):

```
df['columnname'] = df['columnname'].str.replace('([+,])', '', regex = True).astype('int')
```

Takes your column called columname, and replaces the + or , to nothing, then changes the type to integer.

Comment: I tried but the error that appears is "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Free'"

Comment: That error means some of the cells are empty, which can not be converted to an int. Fill the empty cells with 0 using replace then run my code.